# Creating a new column based on specific rows in already existing column with case_when and ifelse condition

Tags: r, if-statement, case-when

I've been struggling to find a way to reprint the values of certain rows into a new column based on a specific condition. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Name    V1  V2   V3 
name1   a   a1  yes     
name2   b   b1  yes
name3   c   c1  no
name3   d   d1  yes
```

I would like to create a new column using case_when or ifelse to reprint what is in the second column if V3 is yes, or add the first and second column if V3 is no. To look something like this:

```
Name    V1  V2   V3 V4
name1   a   a1  yes a1  
name2   b   b1  yes a1
name3   c   c1  no  c+c1
name3   d   d1  yes d1
```

However, one issue Ive been running into is that my values are not all logical or all characters and are a mix of both. V3 are characters while V2 is a timestamp and V1 is a seconds time. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse` with `transform` in `base R`

```
df1 <- transform(df1, V4 = ifelse(V3 == "no", paste0(V1, "+", V2), V2))
```

If these are not strings, then use `V1 + V2` and remove the `paste0`

-ouput

```
df1
  Name V1 V2  V3   V4
1 name1  a a1 yes   a1
2 name2  b b1 yes   b1
3 name3  c c1  no c+c1
4 name3  d d1 yes   d1
```

NOTE: If the columns 'V2', 'V1' are of different class, convert both to `character` class before doing the `ifelse`

```
df1[c("V1", "V2")] <- lapply(df1[c("V1", "V2")], as.character)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(V4 = case_when(V3 == "no" ~ str_c(V1, "+", V2), TRUE ~ V2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name3"), 
    V1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), V2 = c("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"
    ), V3 = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: @GenLG then you use the `V1 + V2` instead of `paste`